# Openlayers - Loop through control collection

Tags: openlayers-2, mapcontrol

Is there a way to loop through the collection of map controls that have been added to an OpenLayers map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered my own question. This one was painfully obvious and I don't know why I didn't see it earlier.

Here is the code for looping over the control collection:

```
function fcnLoopThruControlCollection() {
   var mControls = map.controls;

   for (var a = 0; a < mControls.length; a++) {
        alert(mControls[a].id);
    }
}
```